# htaccess change image php extension to png?

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a WordPress installation. I have an image on this path:

http://www.somedomain.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/image.php

Is it possible to link / rewrite it to this path instead?

http://www.somedomain.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/image.png

Htaccess could be fine. Maybe match `/image.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(script)/([^.]*)\.php$ $1/image.png [L]
```

hopefully it will help you achieve you looking for. Forgive me for any syntax error.

Comment: It should be .png somewhere. However nothing changes.

Comment: yes sorry may be typo error, u can try with diff .htaccess rewrite rules though.. it should be something tricky only